# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program adb.exe CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to run code in android studio gets following Error:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe":
>   CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied

What will be the cause.
Also while creating `AVD` getting this Error:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator-check.exe":
>   CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied

Comment: Can you check if the files exist?

Comment: Yes! both files are exist,
Yesterday It was working perfectly suddenly stop working now

Comment: You didnt understand my answer @MK3007 ? ok whatever your issue is solved. happy to help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a Windows Security issue. You need to give yourself the proper permissions to run ADB.

Using Windows Explorer, navigate to :

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
```

1) Right click on the `adb.exe` icon and select Properties;

2) In the Properties window, select the Security tab;

3) Select your user name and give yourself full control;

4) Click Apply

Why did you have to do this when ADB was working before, you ask? Because you just updated the Android SDK and the new version of ADB overwrote the old version which had the proper permissions.